# Run a virtual environment globally?

Tags: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Is there any way to make `workon` global? For example; I open terminal and type `workon myenvname --global`, then I open another terminal window and type something like `python myscript.py` and it will run it under the `myenvname` environment?

Also I can then open Sublime Text IDE and create a python script, then press `CTRL`+`b` and the python script will run in the `myenvname` environment.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. Virtual environments must be activated in every shell (i.e., every terminal) separately.

There is no magic in Python virtual environments. Their activation just sets a few environment variables; the most important is `PATH` so that the current shell finds `python` and `pip`. Then `python` being run from a virtual env detects it and sets `sys.path` accordingly.

To some extent you can do a trick without activation: run `python` from a virtual env:

```
/path/to/venv/bin/python myscript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps someone

You may not be able to run it globally but if you want to run a particular python script without entering into the virtualenv. Here's a work around.

**Considering you are using this on linux**.

Say you have a virtualenv called `myenvname`

You would like to run a particular python script `myscript.py` inside this particular `myenvname` without even using terminal by just double click on an icon.

Create a shell script `myshellscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# open the virtual environment
source /home/usr_name/.virtualenvs/myenvname

# location to the python script you want to run
# python/python3 depending on the version you are using
python location/to/your/python/script/myscript.py
```

Give permission for `myshellscript.sh` to be an executable

`chmod +x myshellscript.sh`

Create a `.desktop` file inside `/usr/share/applications/`

`sudo nano /usr/share/applications/myscript.desktop`

copy paste the block of code and make the changes accordingly

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=shellscript file to be run along with its path
Path=directory where the file is located
Name=myscript
Comment=comment here
Icon=icon path here
```

then give permission to the `myscript.desktop`

`chmod +x /usr/share/applications/myscript.desktop`

You are done.

Just goto `/usr/share/applications/` and double click on `myscript` icon, you got your `myscript.py` running